# How to add destinations (waypoints) to a route directly by clicking on an POI marker on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

I'm implementing a feature that relevant to Google map -- Trip Plans, which can let the user customize their own trip route on the google map. However, I just implement the function that allows the user to create a destination (waypoint) of their trip via submitting lat/long to the Database then display these waypoint data on google map when loading the TripDetailed view. When I saw the road-tripper website, it has a very cool functionality to let users add destinations (waypoints) to a route directly by clicking on a POI marker on Google Maps, that is when the user clicks a specific POI, it will generate an info window with a 'Add to Trip' button. When the user clicks that button, the selected POI will be added as a waypoint into the existing trip route and google map update the trip route.

[This is my trip plan view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gPBx.png)

[I'd like to click this POI to set it as one of my waypoint in the current route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9E0F.png)

Here is my JS code:

```js
            //Calculate Destination and Display Route on the Google Maps
            function calculateDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService) {
                var waypts = [];
                for (var i = 1; i < destinationcount - 1; i++) { //Get rid of the starting and ending point
                    waypts.push({
                        location: new google.maps.LatLng(Lats[i], Lngs[i]),
                        stopover: true
                    });
                }
                            
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {                    
                //I WANT TO IMPLETEMENT WHEN USER CLICK A POI MARKER ON MAP, IT CAN BE PUSH INTO THE waypts[] array
                    waypts.push({
                        location: new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng()),
                        stopover: true
                    });                    
                    //alert(event.latLng.lat() + ", " + event.latLng.lng());
                });
            
                // Retrieve the start and end locations and create a DirectionsRequest using
                // DRIVING directions.
                directionsService.route({
                    origin: start,
                    destination: end,
                    waypoints: waypts, // Since we need to matching the order sequence with the list on the right, we do not need the optimized waypoints
                    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
                }, function (response, status) {
                    // Route the directions and pass the response to a function to create
                    // markers for each step.
                    if (status === 'OK') {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        renderDirectionsPolylines(response);
                    } else {
                        if (status === 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
                            window.alert('Directions request failed due to No route could be found between the origin and destination.');
                            for (i = 0; i < destinationcount - 1; i++) {
                                var id = i + 1;
                                document.getElementById("distance." + id).innerHTML = " Unable to get the distance from the next destination of the current trip.";
                            }
                            document.getElementById("distance." + destinationcount).innerHTML = " This is the end of your trip.";
                            document.getElementById("totaldistance").innerHTML = " Unable to get the total distance of the current trip";
                        }
                        if (status === 'UNKNOWN_ERROR') {
                            window.alert('A directions request could not be processed due to a server error. The request may succeed if you try again.');
                        }
                        if (status === 'REQUEST_DENIED') {
                            window.alert('The webpage is not allowed to use the directions service.');
                        }
                        if (status === 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT') {
                            window.alert('The webpage has gone over the requests limit in too short a period of time.');
                        }
                        if (status === 'NOT_FOUND') {
                            window.alert('At least one of the origin, destination, or waypoints could not be geocoded.');
                        }
                        if (status === 'MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED') {
                            window.alert('Too many DirectionsWaypoints were provided in the DirectionsRequest. Up to 23 waypoints allowed in each request, plus the origin and destination.');
                        }
                        if (status === 'INVALID_REQUEST') {
                            window.alert('The DirectionsRequest provided was invalid.');
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my js code to add a new destination (waypoint) to current trip route, it can get the lat/lng when clicking the map, but I do not know why it cannot be pushed into the waypoint[] array:

```js
                //I WANT TO IMPLETEMENT WHEN USER CLICK A POI MARKER ON MAP, IT CAN BE PUSH INTO THE waypts[] array
                    waypts.push({
                        location: new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng()),
                        stopover: true
                    });                    
                    //alert(event.latLng.lat() + ", " + event.latLng.lng());
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone give me some hints about how I could implement this functionality in javascript? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved this problem. Just using the ajax to post lat/lng to the controller, but I'm thinking about how I can directly break up the polyline to add the waypoints in any order to the current trip route instead of adding it as the last trip destination.

Here is my updated JS code

```js
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                    //Now we using ajax to pass the value from view to controller
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "/Account/AddMapDestination",
                        data: {
                            lat: event.latLng.lat(),
                            lng: event.latLng.lng(),
                            currentTripUid: '@Model.tripUID.ToString()'
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.success) {
                                alert(result.responseText);
                                location.reload(); //We do refresh page here to let page redener Destination result Panes with new sequence id.
                            } else {
                                alert(result.responseText);
                                location.reload();
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error, your trip destination order sequence has not been changed.");
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                   // alert(event.latLng.lat() + ", " + event.latLng.lng());
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```